# Openni_Launch on Lion with Xtion

Tags: openni, macos, ros-fuerte, virtualbox, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just returning to ROS after some time.
How do you get openni_launch installed in OSX?

I've been able to consistently get ROS Fuerte installed on Lion.
using:

> http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

I've been able to get VirtualBox with Ubuntu and Fuerte up and running on Lion out of the box.

I've been able to dual boot and get Fuerte and the Xtion with everything working in Ubuntu on the Macbook Air.

But what I want is to get At Least OpenNI_Launch and Openni_camera etc up and running on Lion. I can run roscore, and everything is fine. But Openni_Launch is not present in OSX and obviously apt-get is not either.

How do I install Openni_Launch in an OSX environment?
I found:

> https://github.com/walchko/kinect

But it seems to be tailored specifically for the kinect even going as far as swapping out usb drivers...

When I get VirtualBox running on Lion with Ubuntu 64x, everything works except that the camera does not display data either in Rviz or RosTopic.

running:

> roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

does FIND the camera in the virtualbox vm of Ubuntu, and everything acts like it's about to work, but there is just no picture and on rostopic the camera node is just not displaying data?

If I could get the camera to work in my VM OR if I could get Openni_Launch to work on Lion this would be sufficient for me.

I just want to utilize to objectiveC and the App store for ROS, so I need to be able to get this running on OSX.

Any Suggestions?
Thoughts??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34571/openni_launch-on-lion-with-xtion/) by [seanreynoldscs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2282/seanreynoldscs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vikas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1768/vikas/) on 2013-09-21**:\

> > does FIND the camera in the virtualbox vm of Ubuntu, and everything acts like it's about to work, but there is just no picture and on rostopic the camera node is just not displaying data?

I have a similar problem on Ubuntu guest with Ubuntu host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The work of Kevin Walchko you found at his github is trying to address this very problem.  I think it is related to problems with the openni_driver on OS X, which has been historically problematic, Kevin can probably comment better here.

As for visualization in the VM, try switching the display to points from billboards of the PointCloud2 type.  For some reason several of the nvidia CG shader scripts do not work properly on Mac (either directly or via a virtual machine).  This is a known problem and it might be fixed in the future, but the current work around is to avoid billboards.

There is no native obj-c client for ROS nor are there wrappers to the c++ ROS client at the moment, but there is a new special interest group (SIG) for exactly this: http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Planning/iOS

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, my kinect work in github uses libfreenect and not OpenNI. I can't get OpenNI to work with ros correctly on OSX (tried many times and many ways). Also you cannot use kinect with VB ... doesn't work.

What I am doing now is running kinect (using libfreenect) to produce depth images and point clouds ros understands. I am right now setting up (just like you did) a virtualbox with Linux and ROS-Fuerte so I can send (over the network) kinect data (from OSX) to virtualbox/Linux and work with RGBD-Slam, octomap, etc.

[kinect] -> [OSX/libfreenect] -> [Virtualbox/Linux]

I have basically given up on an OSX only solution. For the past year, I have spent more time getting ros packages to work on OSX than actually doing any robotics work. I am almost to the point of abandoning OSX and just moving to Linux completely.

Curious how the performance of Linux/Ros is on a macbook air. Also curious about your thoughts on the Xtion if you have any too.

Good Luck!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seanreynoldscs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2282/seanreynoldscs/) on 2012-05-28**:
Linux/Ros on Macbook air works flawlessly. I recommend the tutorial here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir4-2

Please dont give up on OSX!
We just need to get OpenNI_Launch working on the Macbook!

What success have you had getting OpenNI to port?

**Comment by [seanreynoldscs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2282/seanreynoldscs/) on 2012-05-28**:
I really really like the Xtion, It's flawless! The best thing about it is that it doesnt require external power; much better for robotics. The worst thing about it is that there are other projects which are Kinect Specific.

How can I attempt to install Openni_Launch into ros on OSX? Sorry I'm new.

**Comment by [seanreynoldscs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2282/seanreynoldscs/) on 2012-05-28**:
Is it: "rosdep install openni_launch" ?